# Keep path within axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}                                                                                                                                                                           
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot [name path = plot1] coordinates {
      (0, 2)
      (2, 5)
      (3, 7)
    };
    \draw [name path = plot2] (0, 2) -- (5, 2);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the path `plot2` extends out of the `axis` scope as seen in the result:

[image]

How to make the `axis` adjust itself to enclose the path `plot2` as much as it does the adjustment to enclose the path `plot1`?

Comment: Your definition of "within" is a bit strange, that line is cut off, so it never (visibly) goes outside the axis. Are you after something like `\draw [name path = plot2] (0, 2) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}-0.5, 2);`? Or `\draw [name path = plot2] (0, 2) -- (end |- 5, 2);`, after adding `coordinate (end)` at the end of the first `\addplot`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I want `axis` to adjust itself to enclose completely the path `plot2` as much as it does the adjustment to enclose the path `plot1`.

Comment: Any reason why you can't use `\addplot` for that line as well?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. In the end I would be using `\path` as the path `plot2` does not need to be drawn. Can I use `\addplot` to construct a path and not draw the actual line?

Comment: `\addplot [draw=none,name path = plot2] coordinates {(0, 2)(5, 2)};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pgpflots` doesn't take `\path`s into account when calculating the bounding box, but you can draw the line with `\addplot` instead. If the line should not be visible, add `draw=none` to the `\addplot` settings.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}                                                                                                                                                                           
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot [name path = plot1] coordinates {
      (0, 2)
      (2, 5)
      (3, 7)
    } coordinate (end);
    \addplot [draw=none,name path = plot2] coordinates {(0, 2)(5, 2)};

    \addplot [blue!10] fill between[of=plot1 and plot2];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```